# How to guarantee the topic events order generated by debezium, stored in kafka and sent to spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, debezium, change-data-capture

I am working in a change data capture project. I have a mysql database. I use debezium to capture all the changes and send it to kafka. And later I read all the info from Spark and I send it to Apache Phoenix using jdbc.

I am using debezium with a rerouting option which send the changes of all the tables to only one kafka topic. With this configuration I am sure I can read the unique kafka topic from spark in order.

But my question is: If I use debezium without the rerouting option and I have every table changes in a different kafka topic, how could I guarantee I read the events of all the topics in the correct order?

I know I can use Spark to order it for example by timestamp but if say, one kafka topic is offline 10 minutes because a problem arise but the other kafka topics continue working I will have in Spark an ordering problem.

How can I face this problem?

Comment: Note: You could use the same Debezium server to run Kafka Connect JDBC Sink rather than use Spark

Comment: If you must process events in a particular order, then you must write them to a single partition by their ordering key. That way, they are consumed in that order... I'm not quite understanding why Spark or Phoenix would have issues with that, though, but I think when you run a query, you want to guarantee you have all events up to a certain time? (Which is a batch use-case, and maybe using Sqoop from MySQL to HBase on a schedule would be more what you are looking for)

Comment: My use case is real time. Imagine a user realize 5 transactions in 2  MySQL tables. In that case I will have in kafka 2 topics for example in the topic 1: the 1st,2nd,5th transaction and in the topic 2: 3rd, 4th transaction. If due to a hypothetical problem the kafka topic 2 is stopped or delayed (Im not sure if this situation is possible, but I think so) then when I order the events in Spark I only will have the events from topic 1. Spark will order it and the result of that ordering will be: transaction 1, transaction 2 and transaction 5 and that events will be pushed out to Phoenix...

Comment: Do you have GTIDs enabled? If yes does Spark support something like Kafka Streams session windowing? If yes then you could group all events belongig to the same transaction based on GTID in the event.

Comment: @Jiri Pechanec. Yes, I have GTID enabled but I think Spark only allow windowing on timestamp, not on other fields. If I read from more than 1 kafka topic, I don't know how is possible to guarantee the order because even using windowing (with timestamp or gtid) there is always the possibility the last event read in the Spark window is not trully the last. Like I expose in my previous message, I can only order what I have read during the duration of the window but this technic doesn't guarantee me the possibility of having in some Kafka topic events more recent events than the events I have read

Comment: Imagine for example a topic delay (in only 1 kafka topic). Or imagine for example I have 50 topics and Spark can not read all in parallel and read first 4 topics, later another 4 topics and so on. In that case the problem I expose would be possible. I'm wrong or I'm understanding something in a wrong way?

Comment: I am afraid the only one option for you is to place a simple Kafka Streams aggregation pipeline between Debezium and Spark and first aggregate events per transaction using session windowing. You could then aply time based windowing in Spark.

Comment: @Jiri Pechanec. I understand. Finally I'd like to ask you: Do you think using the rerouting option having all the mysql tables changes in only one kafka topic is a bad and slow approach? or in your opinion would be better to have every table changes in different topics and to try the reordering technichs we have spoken about (in Kafka and Spark)?

Comment: @zamora14 It is definitely viable option but you need to think about drawbacks. IIRC correctl you'd like to apply all events serially. This means that you'd need to have a single partiion per topic which means that you are completely losing horizonatl scalability. It might be unnecessary for your traffic/use-case but this is something that needs to be measured.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem with this configuration on Debezium

```
{
"name": "name-connector",
"config": {
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "database.hostname": "0.0.0.0",
    "database.port": "5433",
    "database.user": "postgres",
    "database.password": "******",
    "database.dbname" : "database",
    "database.server.name": "database",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.database",
    "decimal.handling.mode" : "string",
    "time.precision.mode" : "connect",
    "tombstones.on.delete" : false,
    "transforms":"routerTopic",
    "transforms.routerTopic.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ByLogicalTableRouter",
    "transforms.routerTopic.topic.regex":"database.public.(.*)",
    "transforms.routerTopic.topic.replacement":"database.public",
}
}
```

configure topic routing with transforms.routerTopic.topic.regex and transforms.routerTopic.topic.replacement

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/0.10/configuration/topic-routing.html